# Is there a way to sort test run results freely in Testrail?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testrail

I use Testrail for test case management. I want to be able to sort the test run results, I have group by and order by, but I would like to be able to sort them randomly.
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

Click on "Suite" at the right top of the test run.

Once you are in the suite, use the "double-arrow" to drag and drop the test cases in the desired order.

That's it, the default order of the test run will be the same order in the test suite.